# List of random values with Rng library

Tags: scala, random, scalaz

I am looking through [Rng](https://github.com/NICTA/rng) sources to see how they generate a list of random values.

They define a function `fill`:

```
def fill(n: Int): Rng[List[A]] = sequence(List.fill(n)(this))
```

where `sequence` is just an invocation of `Traverse.sequence` from `scalaz`:

```
def sequence[T[_], A](x: T[Rng[A]])(implicit T: Traverse[T]): Rng[T[A]] =
  T.sequence(x)
```

In other words they create a temporary list `List[Rang[A]]` and then apply `sequence: List[Rng[A]] => Rng[List[A]]`. I see how it works but the temporary list looks list a waste of memory to me. Is it absolutely necessary ? Can it be improved ?

Comment: In functional programming purity and elegance is much more important than memory consumption :)

Comment: The JVM is very good at dealing with short-lived garbage objects, and the scala compiler inlines a lot. It would probably be possible to avoid the temporary with e.g. a manual imperative loop and a cast, but this would be error-prone and I doubt there would be a noticeable difference in performance. If you think it's really important, write an alternative implementation and profile them (in a real-world app) to demonstrate the difference.

Answer (score 1):

This is a slightly faster implementation. I didn't profile to see if there was a noticeable impact on the heap. I did a rough timing test and it took roughly 70% of the time `Rng.fill` took to fill a 1M item list with random Ints. I didn't attempt to find out how these scaled with different size lists. See https://gist.github.com/drstevens/77db6bab6b1e995dac13

```
def fill[A](a: Rng[A], count: Int): Rng[List[A]] =
  Stream.from(0).take(count).traverseU(_ => a).map(_.toList)
```

The interesting thing about this is that the toList isn't evaluated until `unsafePerformIO`.